# How to parse a .eml file in Java

Tags: java, encryption, outlook, base64, eml

I need some help. I'm working with .eml file which I want to parse but I couldn't understand certain portion of the file like this(bold one)from the term Content:Disposition I can understand it's an attachment attached in the mail. 
Could you please help me decrypt the bold part,which information does it contains. Thanks in advance. 
**--_007_D60D14D231DE2E479723896E22F398618F36F010INBLRDAGND3corp_**

`--_007_D60D14D231DE2E479723896E22F398618F36F010INBLRDAGND3corp_
   Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
   officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;name="Page-Copy.docx"Content-Description: Page-Copy.docxContent-Disposition: attachment; filename="Page-Copy.docx"; size=245714;creation-date="Tue, 31 Jul 2018 06:14:01 GMT";modification-date="Tue, 31 Jul 2018 06:14:03 GMT"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`

[Please refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaaNT.png)

Comment: That is I guess the part boundary of a multipart message. You should see a similar string that will end the part.

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj is right. The boundary is set in the header of the message, then all part of this multi-part message are separated by such a string.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple:

An email message might be formed in a variety of content-types:

- text/plain For messages which contain olny text.
- text/html For messages in HTML.
- multipart/* For messages that contain some attachments. In this case, the message contains one body for the main text and one body for each attached file, separed through a long string called *boundary*. See [RFC1341](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html) for a complete reference.